# How to modify the coordinates of a feature (eg LINE) on the fly?

Tags: java, geotools

I want to change the coordinates of a line and draw it with new coordinates on the fly. Although the values can be changed, I had not success to repaint with new coordinates.
My Sample code and traced outputs are here..

TRACE-1:SimpleFeatureImpl:OSB_Line=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom=MULTILINESTRING ((32.56891053280672 39.98170079260158, 32.56195765663663 39.98391357917568)),

TRACE-2:SimpleFeatureImpl:OSB_Line=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom=MULTILINESTRING ((132.5689105328067 39.98170079260158,

```
public void modifySelectedFeatures(Set<FeatureId> idSet) {
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(null);
    MapContent mapContent = mapFrame.getMapContent();
    FeatureLayer layer = (FeatureLayer) mapContent.layers().get(0);
    Filter filter = ff.id(idSet);
    try {
        SimpleFeatureCollection fColl = (SimpleFeatureCollection) layer.getFeatureSource().getFeatures(filter);
        if (!fColl.isEmpty()) {
            SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = fColl.features();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature simpleFeature = iterator.next();
                System.out.println("TRACE-1:" + simpleFeature);
                Geometry geom = (MultiLineString) simpleFeature.getDefaultGeometry();
                Coordinate c = geom.getCoordinates()[0];
                c.setCoordinate(new Coordinate(c.x + 100.0, c.y, c.z));
                simpleFeature.setDefaultGeometry(geom);
                System.out.println("TRACE-2:" + simpleFeature);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    mapFrame.getMapPane().repaint();
}
```